# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' for the version tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

This issue was raised before as well but the problem persists for me. I am trying to build a 
training detector model using tensorflow. I will tell whatever I have tried so far :

1. Replacing tf.contrib with TPUStrategy. Any suggestions on applying this feature on my code will be 
   grateful. (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26513)
2. Tried installing pycocotools for model_main.py
3. Instead of "import tensorflow as tf" tried "import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf"
4. Tried replacing "contrib" with "experimental"
5. Tried installing tensorflow addons

As per the release notes https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha0 , it says 
tf.contrib has been deprecated, and functionality has been either migrated to the core TensorFlow API, to tensorflow/addons or removed entirely.
If it is migrated to tensorflow addons, which addon is it?
I've tried almost everything.
Tensorflow Version: 2.0

Getting error in the line:

```
slim_example_decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder
```

Can anyone provide me with any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tensorflow.contrib` does not exist anymore. Any code that relies on it is obsolete and needs to be updated (and this is no trivial task).

As of now, the tensorflow object detection API still does not support Tensorflow 2.0, because most of the models in the API are built with TF Slim, which was part of contrib an has been dropped. There is an external package for slim, but AFAIK that's not officially supported (and it's a temporary solution, at best).

Until the object detection API supports TF2, your quickest solution is to downgrade your tensorflow to 1.15.

Comment: I have downgraded tensorflow 2.0 to tensorflow 1.14 and made the object from scratch Now I ran the same code (train.py). After removing the errors (used tf.compat.v1 instead of tf), a the long list of errors. I seek your guidance on this: